# Normalized audio in sox: no such file

Tags: audio, sox

I'm trying to use this script to batch normalize audio using Sox. I'm having a problem because it appears that it's not creating a tmp file for some reason and then of course there is no normalized audio file either. I'm getting this error for every file:

```
norm_fade.sh: line 57: /Applications/sox/WantNotSamples/Who Am I-temp.wav: No such file or directory
Normalized File "wav_file" exists at "/Applications/sox/WantNotSamplesNormalize"
rm: /Applications/sox/WantNotSamples/Who Am I-temp.wav: No such file or directory
```

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh   
#  Script.sh
#
#
#  Created by scacinto on 1/31/13.
#
#  For now, only put audio files in the working directory - working on a fix

# This is the directory to the source soundfiles that need to be
# normalized and faded (the first argument on the command line.)
src=$1
# This is the directory to write the normalized and faded files to
# (The second path you must supply on the command line.)
dest=$2
#  This is the sox binary directory.  Please set this to your sox path.
#  As it is now, this assumes that the sox binary is in the same directory
#  as the script.
SOX= ./sox

#enable for loops over items with spaces in their name
IFS=$'\n'

#  This is the 'for' loop - it will run for each file in your directory.
for original_file in `ls "$src/"`
do
# Get the base filename of the current wav file
base_filename=`basename "$original_file" .wav`

# We need a temp file name to save the intermediate file as
temp_file="${base_filename}-temp.wav"

echo "Creating temp file: \"$temp_file\" in \"$src\""

# And we need the output WAV file
wav_file="${base_filename}-nf.wav"

# Convert all spaces to hyphens in the output file name
wav_file=`echo $wav_file | tr -s " " "-"`

#Print a progress message
echo "Processing: \"$original_file\". Saving as \"$wav_file\" ..."

# We need the length of the audio file
original_file_length=`$SOX $src/"$original_file" 2>&1 -n stat | grep Length | cut -d : -f 2 | cut -f 1`

# Use sox to add perform the fade-in and fade-out
# saving the result as our temp_file.  Adjust the 0.1s to your desired fade
# times.
#$SOX $src/"$original_file" $src/"$temp_file" fade t 0.1 $original_file_length 0.1

# If files have readable headers, you can skip the above operation to get the
# file length and just use 0 as below.
#$SOX $src/"$original_file" $src/"$temp_file" fade t 0.5 0 0.5

# normalize and write to the output wave file
$SOX $src/"$temp_file" $dest/"$wav_file" norm -0.5

echo "Normalized File \"wav_file\" exists at \"$dest\""

# Delete that temp file
rm $src/$temp_file

done
```

Comment: It probably doesn't help that the line for creating the temp file is commented out.

Comment: Unfortunately I must be missing it as temp_file="${base_filename}-temp.wav doesn't appear to be commented out. The $SOX $src/ code towards the bottom are commented out because they are performing actions that I don't need.

Comment: assigning a name to a variable doesn't create a file. You have a commented out line that invoked sox to do a fade out into the temp file.

Comment: That's exactly correct. How did I miss that? Thanks for the help and edits @jaket!